# VirtualHost requests are beign mixed

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a quite busy server (around 10-15 requests per second) which serve web pages for several domains. Today I just realized that sometimes, the "requests" are mixed. The impact is very little (0.01% maybe) but definitively a problem.

In example, I have the following scripts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email1@myhostname1.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/host1
    ServerName myhostname1.com

    ...
    ...

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/host1.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email1@myhostname2.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/host2
    ServerName myhostname2.com

    ...
    ...

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/host2.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

However, sometimes in the host2.access.log appear requests that should be done to host1, and viceversa, like apache would be mixing requests. I also see lots of 408 errors with very small times (definitively not a timeout, but something wrong going on). Those 408 errors also seem to be from other virtual servers.

Is there any known issue/bug of apache which can cause this problem?

The apache error.log when using apachectl restart shows:

```
[Sat May 09 11:40:11 2015] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for srv01
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Sat May 09 11:40:11 2015] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Sat May 09 11:40:11 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Thanks!

EDIT: the "mixed" acesses with files which should be accessible from the other server also have a 408.

Comment: Are you using pre-form or MPM model?

Comment: Is it only with exactly 2 virtual hosts where logs/requests are swapped? Or is it more than that and you were giving us a short example?

Comment: I think maybe your 408 errors are due to the server being overloaded and not getting to the request in time for it to be properly handled. If that is the case, then _maybe_ Apache is dropping the request before it is assigned to the proper VirtualHost, and therefore is getting put into the "default" VM. But like BazzaDP said, that explains why host2 appears in host1's logs, not the other way around. It might be because Apache will simply use the configuration of the most-recently handled request.

Comment: Do you have SSL configured for this virtual hosts?

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm a newbie in server management :) As far as I know I'm not using MPM. I have several Virtual hosts, but all the fails seem to appear to the same Virtual Host. Removing that VirtualHost just makes that another VirtualHost receives the 408s. I have one VirtualHosts with SSL, but the others one not (the SSL one is not 'sending' nor 'receiving' mixed requests

Comment: As far as I know, my server is not heavy loaded. It's a 4-core but its load average is between 1.0 and 2.0 most of the time

Comment: I found a very similar problem online although with no solution : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/virtual-host-generating-408-errors-even-though-file-is-served-correctly-4175519738/      I'm not sure if all my requests are served because I have no way to check it (users make multiple requests to the server)

Answer (score 2):

Not aware of any bugs but Apache 2.2 is getting a bit long in the tooth now. And while we're on the subject openssl 0.9.8 that I notice you're using is definitely getting too old (it won't support TLS 1.1 or 1.2, and only 0.9.8o and upwards - which you are admittedly on - support SHA-2 certs which are quickly becoming necessary as browsers stop supporting SHA-1 certs).

Anyway, the first config will be used by default if no ServerName or ServerAlias matches the request. So if someone goes to www.myhostname2.com then it will return the first host rather than the second as you might expect based on the fact that only myhostname2.com (without the www) is specified in your config for second host. You should add ServerAlias config if you need multiple names. Similarly there are issues on older operating systems/browsers for TLS requests on port 443 but you seem to only be talking about http (port 80) here.

However I can't explain the reverse (going to host 2 config when you expect host 1).

Have a read of this page which explains exactly how this should be set up:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html
There are also some comments at the  bottom about the wrong config being picked up depending on order but I don't understand why that would be based on the limited info they've given.

Comment: Apache 2.2 might be getting old, but moving to 2.4 can be a b**ch thanks to some major configuration changes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to have a look at ServerAlias, however shouldn't the problem appear always and not sporadically?  I upgraded all the packages after I made the request (through apt-get) but OpenSSL did not change (apache didn't move to 2.4 obviously). Unfortunately I'm not confident enough to move those packages manually :(  (if the problem would become more than a nuissance I'd get another server, upgrade to latest, and when working do a data migration)

Comment: Well it could be 99.99% of people are sending a server name of  myhostname2.com and your 0.01% are sending www.myhostname2.com so they are the only ones being sent to the default (myhostname1). Adding a server alias will solve this (for http/port 80 at least) if that is the case. Apache logs won't show this by default so you'd need to add %v to the log format to see if this is the case. However, as I said, this still doesn't explain hostname1 requests being logged in hostname2 logs so not 100% convinced that's the issue if you are seeing that...